# Setting max-width for HTML export in Emacs org-mode

Tags: org-mode

When I export an org-mode file to HTML, I'd like to limit the line width to make it easier to read.  Can setting max-width with #+ATTR_HTML: help me do that?  If so, how?  If not, is there a way?  I'd prefer doing it on a per-file basis rather than globally or per-paragraph.

I'm using Emacs 23.3.1 and org-mode 7.8.03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hi**, there.
Note that using only the *max-width* tag as advised above will place the entire body content to left by default. If you wanted, additionally, to center it on the screen, you need to add and set the *margin* tag to auto by adding  `margin: auto;`
It makes it to look much better for me, try it.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about that attribute, and it can help.  I had already set the left margin to 1 inch, which I think did even better for me.  Automatic margins caused the material to shift horizontally as I expanded and contracted sections.

Answer (score 10):

You can setup css style to limit max-width on a per-file basis:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">body{ max-width:50%; }</style>
```

Also there is a way on per-heading setup:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">#outline-container-introduction{ max-width:30%; }</style>
```

and then set property of concrete heading:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: introduction
:END:
```

Upd.: Replaced `#+STYLE` by `#+HTML_HEAD`

Comment: Thanks!  Your first suggestion (with 50% changed to 6in or the like) did exactly what I wanted.  I think I need to re-learn CSS.

Comment: I just made use of this, but I found that the org-mode syntax has since changed so this answer works only if you replace STYLE with HTML_HEAD see this note on the org-mode website: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-8.0.html#sec-8